# $p_1=1-x-2x^2,\ p_2=3+x,\ p_3=5-x+4x^2,\ p_4=-2-2x+2x^2$ do these polynomials span $p_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine whether these polynomials span $P_2$ $$p_1=1-x-2x^2\\
> p_2=3+x\\ p_3=5-x+4x^2\\ p_4=-2-2x+2x^2$$

I tried solving the system but have no idea what to do
when solving. Can you please help?

which is 
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-2\\ 
3&1&0\\ 
5&-1&4\\
-2&-2&2\end{bmatrix}

---

Comment: Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @almagest, the OP probably means $P_2$, the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The dimension of the space generated by these polynomials is the rank of the matrix you have written. The rank can be found by using row reduction.